# JavaScript - send image to server as binary data

Tags: javascript, arrays, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I have an Image object

```
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
   var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,W,H);
```

How can I now pass `imgData` as binary data (or a string) to the server using POST method?

Comment: This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must get byte array of the image. It's easy:

```
let bytes = imgData.data
```

Then, send bytes to server. It's simple too:

```
fetch('https://example.net/',{method: 'POST', body: bytes}).then((res) => ...)
```

But, as a matter of fact, their is very few server which receive raw image data. In reality, send processed data such as jpeg compression and base64 encoding.

Comment: Ahh, right... I've been trying to send `imgData` instead of `imgData.data`. It seems it works with xmlhttprequest as well. Thanks.